# DiscordClient not recognized

Tags: c#, discord.net

Hey I am trying to create a bot using c#, but am getting an error when I type DiscordClient. 
this is my program.cs file

```
using System;

namespace firstbot
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyBot bot = new MyBot();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the MyBot.cs file

```
using System;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace firstbot
{
public class MyBot
{
    DiscordClient discord; //error comes here
    public MyBot()
    {



    }
   }
  }
```

the error is:
the type of namespace DiscordClient could not be found. I am not sure what is wrong and need some help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Install-Package DiscordSharp + add using.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, newer releases of Discord.NET (>0.9) no longer use `DiscordClient`.
You have to use `DiscordSocketClient` instead.

You have an example [here](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/dev/docs/guides/getting_started/samples/intro/structure.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install **Discord.net** :

1. Go to ***Project*** at the top and select ***Manage Nuget Packages***
2. Once in the Nuget package manager, search for **"Discord.Net"**
3. Make sure ***Include prerelease*** is checked next to the search bar.
4. Install the top option : **Discord.Net v1.0.1**