# DiscordClient not found and LogMessageEventArgs error

Tags: c#, discord.net

[The error messages in the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzM5R.jpg) Upon running the code I get multiple errors about the `DiscordClient` which could not be found and the `LogMessageEventArgs` which could not be found. I have checked for an answer but most say to its due to updates, I have the latest update but it is still an error. Could anyone suggest how I could change the code to make it work?

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189148/discordclient-not-recognized) article was incorrect for the 1.02 version of Discord.NET which I am running.

```
class MyBot
{
    DiscordClient Discord;

    public MyBot()
    {
        Discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log;
        });

        Discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await Discord.Connect("TZr9Hmj2X9S7NdR8-JK5fYGKUv3kvomb", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }

    private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the full error/exception and stacktrace?

Comment: yeah sure i will add it to the post

Comment: Ok, this is a `build-time` error. I was confused by `running  the code`. You need to ensure that the types are accessible by using `using` statements, like `using  Discord;`. It's what the error says: you are missing a `using`directive, or a reference.

Comment: I am using both "using Discord;" and "using Discord.Commands;"

Comment: Yet the `DiscordClient` does not exist. Don't they have a tutorial at their site? It should contain the correct namespaces.

Comment: Mmm the latest nightly is 2.0.x beta

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall all discord.net packages that aren't version 0.9.6, then run the NuGet command line and type "Install-Package Discord.Net -Version 0.9.6" and "Install-Package Discord.Net.Commands -Version 0.9.6" this should fix all problems.

Comment: Why would you even use 0.9.6? D.NET is on 2.x and it is hilarious. Upgrade already.

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked already says that for Discord.Net (>0.9) you need to use `DiscordSocketClient` instead of `DiscordClient`.